# License issue while accessign with domain

Tags: 2013, dd4t

I am facing one common issue but in strange manner. It is coming only when I am accessing it with URL. with IP and port application is working fine.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.tridion.broker.StorageException: License is not valid or expired, the requested DAO was mapped to non-filesystem binding and could not be loaded.
```

Comment: Do you have the "cd_license.xml" in your /bin/config of your web application as well? Do you have the URL listed in your "cd_dynamic_conf.xml "?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have more than one server in your NLB.

If you are getting this error while accessing the application with the domain URL  and not the individual IP and port, there is a very high chance that one of the application servers part of the Network Load Balancer does not have the right license file OR no license (or incorrect location mentioned in config files) OR has an incorrect cd_storage_config.xml which points to FS as default storage